# Set TextBox value using javascript on ButtonClick in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have searched alot but i didn't find any good answer.
My Question is:

> I want to set the value of a asp.net textbox using external javascript
>   file.

```js
function setvalue()
{
document.getElementById('<%=txtbox1.ClientID %>').value = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="setvalue();" Text="SetValue" />
```

i have found some answer but they used internal javascript.
I don't know how to do it.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the textbox's ID as parameter, like this

```
function setvalue(textBoxID)
{
  document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = "Hello World";
}
```

and in your main file (asp/aspx) call it like this

```
OnClientClick="setvalue('<%=txtbox1.ClientID %>');"
```